# Android FragmentTabHost fail landscape

Tags: android, tabs, tabwidget

i've a fragmenttab host, with a tab widget and a framelayout like this :

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TabWidget 
        android:id="@+id/tabswidget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="90" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm loading my "content" below the tabs in the framelayout.
The problem I meet, is when I set the phone to landscape, I've the top of my content which is "hidden".

I tried to set margin in my tabs, but nothing works...

Comment: what do you mean by hidden? Please post some screenshots to help understand what exactly you want (and have)

Comment: In phone portrait, i've my tabs and below my content. The first element of my content is a layout, with a blue background.
When I set the phone to landscape, the half of this layout is hidden..

Comment: (seems to be hidden by tabs..)

Comment: nodoby has an idea ? :(